# If one shows that UNIQUE k-SAT is in P, does it imply P=NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability, p-vs-np

Valiant & Vazirani proved SAT is reducible to UNIQUE SAT under randomized probabilistic reductions in polynomial time.  Calabro *et al*. showed that UNIQUE k-SAT is as hard as k-SAT. Now the question is, if someone shows that UNIQUE k-SAT is in P,  does it imply P=NP?

**References**

1. L. G. Valiant and V. V. Vazirani, "NP is as easy as detecting unique solutions." *Theoretical Computer Science* 47:85–93, 1986. ([PDF](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397586901350) on ScienceDirect.)
2. C. Calabro, R. Impagliazzo, V. Kabanets and R. Paturi, "The Complexity of Unique k-SAT: An Isolation Lemma for k-CNFs".  *Journal of Computer and System Sciences* 74(3):386–393, 2008. ([PDF](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1332259) at ACM Digital Library; [free PDF](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~kabanets/papers/CIKP.pdf).)

Comment: Valiant & Vazirani showed that SAT is reducible to UNAMBIGUOUS SAT under RP reductions. In second case you are speaking about UNIQUE SAT which is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is still an open question; [**UP**](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:U#up) is not known to be equivalent to **NP**.  In the paper ["NP Might Not Be As Easy As Detecting Unique Solutions,"](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~fortnow/papers/newiso.pdf) Beigel, Burhman and Fortnow construct an oracle under which **P** contains **UP** but **P** is still not equivalent to **NP**.

Comment: just a minor note: Charles Rackoff in 1982 on Relativized Questions Involving Probabilistic Algorithms (https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/322290.322306), he showed that UP = P and P != NP under some oracle. The paper you mentioned is stronger than the later since Rackoff's paper conditioned that UP has exactly one accepting path for all inputs.