# If NP is easy on average then does it mean P=NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, np, p-vs-np, randomness

If $NP=RP$ then $NP$ is easy on average. Then from point $1$ in abstract in http://lance.fortnow.com/papers/files/derand.pdf which says $NP$ is easy on average implies $P=BPP$ do we have $NP=RP\implies P=NP$?

This problem asks directly a point with respect to a remark in a paper.

I do not blindly ask if np=rp then is p=np. I ask about a comment in a paper.

---

I think essentially I am asking is $RP\subseteq Avg-P$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If one shows that UNIQUE k-SAT is in P, does it imply P=NP?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33225/if-one-shows-that-unique-k-sat-is-in-p-does-it-imply-p-np)

Comment: @KyleJones, can you explain the connection a bit more explicitly?